# OkObjectResult to Model type conversion

Tags: asp.net-core, casting, type-conversion, asp.net-core-webapi

In my project, I have a situation where a get method's return type is **OkObjectResult**

```
public IActionResult GetById(int Id)
{
...
return Ok(returnObj);
}
```

I have to invoke it in another place & convert it into the model type of that method.

```
public IActionResult AnotherMethod(int Id)
{
    ...
    var data = (Model)GetById(Id); //casting
    return Ok(returnObj);
}
```

I have used **casting** but it shows error in the output **Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult' to type 'Entities.Model'**.

Is it possible to convert it in the model type somehow?

Comment: Why not put the contents of GetById() (minus the return Ok()) to a function and call that from both?

Comment: @juunas Actually, I wanted to reuse the GetById(int Id) instead of creating another function to avoid complexity & writing the same thing again & again. Is there any way to **convert** it?

Comment: Could you please tell me which result you want to return inside the AnotherMethod, you want to get the OK result's model and use it in another method? ?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I need the Model type that I've used in GetById(int Id) & I will use that Model type in one place of AnotherMethod(int Id) method. The AnotherMethod(int Id) will also return OkObjectResult

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I suggest you could use ObjectResult.Value to get the OK object result.

More details, you could refer to below test demo:

```
    public IActionResult GetById()
    {
        var re = new List<Projects>() { new Projects { projectID=1, projectMagName="1", projectName="aaa" }, new Projects { projectID=2, projectName="2", projectMagName="bbb" } ,
            new Projects { projectID=3, projectMagName="ccc", projectName="ccc" } };

        return Ok(re);
    }
```

Get its value:

```
      var result=  GetById();
        var re1 = (List<Projects>)((ObjectResult)result).Value;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also slightly different scenario: Async Task

The class address is what we want to get our hands to if you have your IActionResult wrapped in a Task. *If you await the var result = GetById() then you would not need to do .Result when casting.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById()
    {
        ...Do your stuff
        return Ok(new Address() {Street="1 Oliver Street, London"});
    }
    
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoingSomethingWithAddresses() 
    {
        var result = GetById();
        var castResultBackToAddressClass=(Address)((OkObjectResult)result.Result).Value;
    }



    public async Task<IActionResult> DoingSomethingWithAddresses() 
    {
        var result = await GetById();
        var castResultBackToAddressClass=(Address)((OkObjectResult)result).Value;
    }
```